# AngularJS push item to first or 0 index of $scope array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Please help me implement this function. I have an array of items in my `$scope`. Now, when I click on the Add Item button, I want to push a new item to the first index or 0 index of that array. Thanks in advance. :)

Here's a working **jsFiddle** to start with: **http://jsfiddle.net/limeric29/7FH2e/**

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    {{data}}<br/>
    <input type="button" ng-click="addItem()" value="Add Item" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
    new String('Item 5'), new String('Item 4'), new String('Item 3'), new String('Item 2'), new String('Item 1')];

    $scope.addItem = function () {
        var c = $scope.data.length + 1;
        var item = new String('Item ' + c)
        $scope.data.push(item);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Solved my problem by using splice() instead of push() and assigning to what array index to insert.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <pre>{{data}}</pre><br/>
    <input type="button" ng-click="addItem()" value="Add Item" />
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
    new String('Item 4'), new String('Item 3'), new String('Item 2'), new String('Item 1')];

    $scope.addItem = function () {
        var c = $scope.data.length + 1;
        var item = new String('Item ' + c)
        $scope.data.splice(0, 0, item);
    };
}
```

Here's the updated **fiddle** for this. **http://jsfiddle.net/limeric29/xvHNe/**

Comment: you can also use `unshift`. it's a common way of preppending elements to an array.

Answer (score 31):

You can use the unshift function.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
$scope.data = [
new String('Item 5'), new String('Item 4'), new String('Item 3'), new String('Item 2'), new String('Item 1')];

$scope.addItem = function () {
    var item = new String('Item ' + c)
    $scope.data.unshift(item);
};
}
```

Comment: This is the best and simpler approach!

Answer (score 18):

```
$scope.data.unshift(item);
```

One line, not sure why the others made it so difficult

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
    new String('Item 4'), new String('Item 3'), new String('Item 2'), new String('Item 1')];

    $scope.addItem = function () {
        var c = $scope.data.length + 1;
        var item = new String('Item ' + c);
        $scope.data.push(item);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, not necessary this operation. You can solve it like this;

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <!-- "$index" is short parameter, "true" statment is reverse parameter -->
    {{data | reverse:$index:true}}<br/>
    <input type="button" ng-click="addItem()" value="Add Item" />
</div>
```