# Add data in the first row of table using Angular.js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I need to bind data in the first row of the table always after submitting the data into database using Angular.js and PHP. Here is my code:

**courseController.js:**

```
var courseApp=angular.module('GofastoHome');
courseApp.controller('coursecontroller',function($scope){
    $scope.buttonName="Submit";
    //console.log($scope.buttonName);
    var id=gup( "e_i" );
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:"php/readCourseData.php",
        success: function(data){
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.courseData=angular.fromJson(data);
            });
        }
    })
    $scope.addCourseData=function(){
        if($scope.coursename==null){
            alert('course name field could not blank');
        }else if($scope.course_short_name==null){
            alert('short name field could not blank');
        }else if($scope.semester==null){
            alert('semester field could not blank');
        }else{
        var userdata={'course_name':$scope.coursename,'course_short_name':$scope.course_short_name,'semester':$scope.semester};
        console.log('userdata',userdata);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"php/addCourse.php",
            data:userdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                console.log('response',response);
                alert(response.msg);
                $scope.coursename=null;
                $scope.course_short_name=null;
                $scope.semester=null;
                $scope.courseData.push(response);
                });
            },
            error: function(result){
                alert(result)
            }
        })
        }
    }
    if(id != ''){
        $scope.buttonName="Update";
        var userdata={'userid':id};
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:"php/editCourseData.php",
            data:userdata,
            success: function(data){
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    var result=JSON.parse(data);
                    $scope.coursename=result[0].course_name;
                    $scope.course_short_name=result[0].short_name;
                    $scope.semester=result[0].semester;
                });
            },
            error: function(data){
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Inside the success function the line `$scope.courseData.push(response)` is responsible to bind data into the table. Here the values are added in the last row of the table.

**addCourse.php:**

```
<?php
$course_name=stripslashes($_POST['course_name']);
$course_short_name=stripslashes($_POST['course_short_name']);
$semester=stripslashes($_POST['semester']);
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '******');
mysql_select_db('go_fasto', $con);
$qry ='INSERT INTO db_course (course_name,short_name,semester) values ("' . $course_name . '","' . $course_short_name . '","' . $semester . '")';
$qry_res = mysql_query($qry);
if ($qry_res) {
        $result['msg'] = "Course has added successfully";
    } else {
         $result['msg'] =  "course could not added ";
    }
$query='SELECT * from db_course order by course_id desc';
$res=mysql_query($query);
$result=mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

**course.html:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable">
<colgroup>
<col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sl. No</th>
<th>Cource Name</th>
<th>Short Name</th>
<th>No of Semester</th>
<th>Edit</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="course in courseData">
<td>{{$index+1 }}</td>
<td>{{course.course_name}}</td>
<td>{{course.short_name}}</td>
<td >{{course.semester}}</td>
<td>
<a  href='#course?e_i={{course.course_id}}'  >
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green'  value='Edit'   >  
</a>
</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here my requirement is when user will submit the data the same data will add inside the table in first row always.

Comment: what error you get after execution

Comment: @ddw147 : I am not getting any error but values are adding in the last row of the table always after each submit.But here i need to add in 1st row of the table always after each submit.

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826766/angularjs-push-item-to-first-or-0-index-of-scope-array

Comment: @ddw147 : No,I used that method but the output is not coming.

Comment: replacing .push with .unshift will do

Comment: @lcycool : yes it started work.Thank you.